# Unreal - Widget not showing up in mobile apk

Tags: android, user-interface, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am a beginner in Unreal Engine and I am trying to create a game for android. I am not able to show UI in mobile package (apk). I tryied all of the compressions. In viewport everything is how it shoud be, but in apk, I can't see any UI, any button. I can see just the joysticks from controllers. I tryed using add to player screen bp node with no result. The code is in the image. [image]

I tried deconnecting the owning player node and still with no results. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your widget screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Unreal engine but in searching for hopefully an answer that would help you I found a tutorial that takes you through creating a UI with a HUD. When I read it the steps appear to clear and pretty concise. Hopefully reading through it may help you figure out what happened. From what I gather everything is based around using widgets to create your UI. This is the site. https://www.raywenderlich.com/167227/unreal-engine-4-ui-tutorial.

Hope this helps

Comment: Tbabk you. Actually there was something wrong with that project. I deleted it and I recreated one. Thank you very much for searching

Comment: Your very welcome. let us know if you get everything to work.

Comment: interesting I wonder why it wasn't working on this particular one. It would definitely be worth recreating and using as an educational learning tool. I'm have issues myself with a c program that is part of a challenge dealing with a 2D array that I'm about to seek help on myself. lol